# Can I swap my fixie frame and still keep all my old components?

Tags: frames, parts

I would like to change the frame of my fixie, it's too small for me now. It's a PureFix Bravo 50 cm, [these are the specs](http://purefixcycles.eu/pages/pure-fix-original-specs).

I would like to change the frame for a bigger one, a 54 or 58 cm one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not likely economically a good move, especially if you're not doing the labor to swap the bike parts yourself (assuming you own the tool to remove the bottom bracket and what not). The bike is a relatively cheap one (~300 dollars), and you're likely to come out better financially by selling the bike and buying a larger one (which may have some slightly different components spec'd on it, such as different crank arm lengths).

50 cm -> 58 cm is quite a large jump as well, but that is a peripheral point.

Comment: What tools would I need?

Comment: Assuming you're not trying to move the fork, you'll need a bunch of hex keys to take off the stem+handlebars, brakes, seatpost. The wheels will come off with a adjustable spanner or quick release. The crankset will probably come off with a large hex key, and then the bottom bracket will need a bottom bracket tool. You'll also need a hacksaw to cut the fork on the new bike, and cable cutters and a chain tool to cut the new brake housing and brake lines as well as size a new chain for the new bike, since it may not be the same length as the current bike.

Comment: Note that for a bicycle, you need bicycle cable cutters, not just your run of the mill electrician's cable cutters since you need to cut the housing. Selling the bike and pocketing the difference (since you may find on the new bike you need a different stem and what not in order to make it fit) is a better idea than trying to transplant the components onto a new bike, esp. if starting with a cheap bike. Note if you do the transplant, you'll be stuck with a frame and a cheap frame like this has little value on its own.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. The thing is, I'm now riding a 50 cm frame being a 1.85 dude. Although I don't feel any back pain while riding, everywhere I read about sizes, they tell me to get a bigger frame.

Comment: I'd guess that the frame is considerably small for someone that tall.